# binomial coefficients and irrationals

Tags: nt.number-theory, ergodic-theory, diophantine-approximation, binomial-coefficients, irrational-numbers

The following, probably either currently impossible to deal with, or
having a negative solution, arose from an ergodic theory question,
presumably itself currently intractible. I am not a number theorist, so
please bear with me.

Let $c $ be a positive real number, let $\theta$ be an irrational real
number, and let $N$ be a positive integer. For real $r$, define $d(r)$ to
be the distance from $r$ to the integers (the norm symbol, $\| r\|$, is
often used to denote this, causing confusion to non-number theorists like
me).

Define subsets of the set of integers in the interval $(N/2, N/2 +
\sqrt N)$,
$$
T_{N,c, \theta} = \left\{k \left| N/2 \leq k \leq N/2 + \sqrt N, \&\ 
d\left({N\choose k}\theta\right) > c \right.\right\}.
$$

My question: is it true that for every irrational $\theta$, there exists
$c$ (depending on $\theta$), such that
$$
\limsup_{N\to \infty} \frac{\left|T_{N,c,\theta}\right|}{\sqrt N} > 0?
$$
That is, do there exist infinitely many $N$ such that for some $c, \eta> 0$,
$|T_{N,c,\theta} |\geq \eta \sqrt N$ (both $\eta$ and $c$ are permitted
to depend on $\theta$)?

Unfortunately, "almost all"-type results (e.g., the set of irrational
$\theta $ for which this doesn't hold is of measure zero) are not useful
for what I'm interested in.

Or is this currently impossible to decide?

Comment: Very similar questions have arisen in dealing with the "pascal-adic" map. Probably you know this. Karl Petersen likely knows as much as anyone about this.

Comment: Good guess, Anthony.  Vershik's Pascal adic map is the origin of this question---and an affirmative answer would yield that the adic map is weakly mixing. If $\exp 2\pi i \theta$ is in the point spectrum (wrt **measurable**, not continuous, eigenfunctions), then the answer to the question here for this particular $\theta$ must be false. But I was hoping that this had been done (by number theorists). Rational points in the point spectrum are relatively easy to dispose of.

Comment: So I'm pretty sure that this has been asked of a lot of people who were unable to prove the weak mixing (of course there is always the chance that it is well known to someone who knows it well, but that this information has not leaked through to the ergodic theorists, but I think this is unlikely).